# What does $\beta$ mean when describing effect sizes?

Tags: regression, correlation, effect-size, beta-distribution

I'm reading a paper which includes a number of lines like the following: 
"positive emotions in the emotional design treatment had a direct effect on transfer $(\beta=3.34,p>.001)$"
The paper itself doesn't explicitly define how $\beta$ is calculated, or what its unit is. Am I reasonable to assume that in the above example, members of the treatment group outperformed the control by 3.34 Standard Deviations?

If so, is this number meaningfully different from measures like Cohen's $d$ or Hedges $g$?

Answer (score 3):

Without any other information, my assumption would be that it is a coefficient from a regression. This assumption would be strengthened if the paper relied on multiple regression.

However, even if the paper doesn't explicitly state what $\beta$ is, it must offer some context for it. What statistics were done?

It seems very unlikely to me that it means a number of standard deviations, but, in some contexts, I suppose it is possible.

Comment: I am afraid that you are right, it is a coefficient. But wouldn't that be a bad case to state it following the typical format of (parameter = ., p-value = .)? I always see this parameter as a calculated statistic that can be directly compared to a p-value in tables (e.g. chi-squared value, t-score, F-score, etc.). If it would be the coefficient value then it is a very bad (at least unorthodox) way of reporting.

Comment: Indeed, more information is necessary to be able to do more with this question than just guessing. Sadly, there are many articles that don't really tell so much more, and this question gives the minimum information just like some articles do. It is so familiar (the lack of information).

Comment: I looked it up. There was no explanation how the p-values were calculated. See here: after  "we ran a series of regression analyses" from Um, Eunjoon, et al. "Emotional design in multimedia learning." *Journal of educational psychology* 104.2 (2012): 485.